# Identify which GKE Node is serving a client request

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have deployed an application on Google Kubernetes Engine. I would like to identify which client request is being services by which node/pod in GKE. Is there a way to map a client request to the pod/node it was serviced by?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question greatly depends on the amount of monitoring and instrumentation you have at your disposal.
The most common way to go about it is to add a prometheus client to the code running on your pods, and use it to write metrics containing labels that can identify the client requests you are interested in.

Once Prometheus scrapes your metrics, they will be enriched with the node/pod emitting them, and you can get the data you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I think The [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api) is what you need. It allows you to expose `Pod` and `node` info to the running `container`. Your application can simply `echo` the content of certain `env variables` containing the information you need. **This way you can see which `Pod` and scheduled on which node is handling a particular request.**

A few words about what it is from **kubernetes documentation**:

> There are two ways to expose Pod and Container fields to a running
>   Container:
>
> - [Environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api)
> - Volume Files
>
> Together, these two ways of exposing Pod and Container fields are
>   called the  *Downward API*.

I would recommend you to take a closer look specifically at [Exposing Pod Information to Containers Through Environment Variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api). The following example `Pod` exposes to the `container` its name as well as node name:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_NODE_NAME MY_POD_NAME;
          sleep 10;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
  restartPolicy: Never
```

It's just an example that I hope meets your particular requirements but keep in mind that you may expose this way many more relevant information. Take a quick look at the list of [Capabilities of the Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api).